# How can I change the layout of the swagger-ui?

Tags: springdoc

How can I change the layout of the swagger-ui?

For layout options, you can use swagger-ui configuration options. What does this mean?

For example:

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.layout=BaseLayout
```

What all are the different options available ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layouts are a special type of component that Swagger UI uses as the root component for the entire application. You can define custom layouts in order to have high-level control over what ends up on the page.

By default, Swagger UI uses **BaseLayout**, which is built into the application. You can specify a different layout to be used by passing the layout's name as the layout parameter to Swagger UI.

There is also **StandaloneLayout**, or you can add you custom layout if necessary:

- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/customization/custom-layout.md

Comment: I went through this, could you please guide what else option that Springdocs API support to be used instead of making any custom changes ?

Comment: What are the other options for layout?

Comment: There are no other options besides [BaseLayout and your customised one](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/customization/custom-layout.md). Either you use BaseLayout, which is default or you implement/code/write your own, as you can see in the url/link above.